# Is there a grammar-checker under linux?

Tags: debian, spell-checking

While there are spell-checkers but AFAIK they are limited to spell-checking. Are there any grammar-checking utilities in free software and more precisely Debian. Even if not in Debian, then in free software. I am using the spell-checking tag as those folks would probably be also interested in this.

Answer (score 5):

`LibreOffice Writer` by default checks grammar as you type. To turn this feature on or off, go to `Tools` -> `Spelling and Grammar`, click the `Options...` button, and check or uncheck `Check grammar as you type`. Note:  `Spelling and Grammar` will only open if your document is not empty (i.e., contains some text).  Tested in Debian 9/Stretch.

If you don't have `LibreOffice` installed, get it with `sudo apt-get install libreoffice`.

`Abiword` also has grammar checking. In Debian, install with `sudo apt-get install abiword abiword-plugin-grammar`. These packages are present in all current Debian GNU/Linux flavors (Stable 8/Jessie, Testing 9/Stretch, and Unstable/Sid).

After starting `Abiword`, go to `Edit` -> `Preferences` -> `Spell Checking` tab, and place a checkmark by the option `Check grammar as you type` to activate the grammar checking.

For both of these, possible grammar errors will be marked by a wavy blue or green underline.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this Python library:

http://www.nltk.org/

You should not look for a Linux program that does this, but for a Python / Java / PHP / C++ app that does this. Any language that can run under Linux will do. I've googled for "python grammar checker".

Comment: I am looking for an app. or apps which would use such libraries so I can simply parse the content I write through the app. and it tells what I did wrong in a helpful manner with some nice GUI.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use Gramma - it is an interactive command-line grammar checker, it is written in Node.js, but you can also download a standalone binary for Linux: https://github.com/caderek/gramma

Answer (score 1):

Another option is the FOSS [LanguageTool](https://languagetool.org) backend, which can integrate into editors [such as](https://github.com/rhysd/vim-grammarous) [vim](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3223), and probably others. It's not the most powerful, but works well enough, and the vim integration is very nice.

Answer (score 0):

There exists [this](https://www.languagetool.org/), which is a Java library/application which comes with word processor plugins and a Web API.